# Bot Framework receiving Facebook Messenger Event

Tags: botframework, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-events

Referral events should send an event according to the documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/m-me-links/). See #2 for more information.

I am trying to receive this event, however, it does not seem as though the event is sent to the bot framework. We verified that the permission is granted with Facebook Messenger setup.  I am using nGrok and can see all messages routed to the bot, however, this event does not show up when using an http://m.me/ link

Are these events supported?

Comment: This should be passed as an event. Which SDK are you using, Node.js or C# and V3 or V4?

Comment: C# Framework v4

Comment: Also, this is for existing users, not new users that trigger the "Get Started" page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to Referral Messages in the Facebook Messenger Developer Portal. Open the settings blade on the left, scroll down to webhooks, and hit edit events.

[image]

Then enable messaging referrals and click save.

[image]

When the user clicks on the m.me link it will open the conversation and send a message activity to the bot. Note, I could only get this behavior to work if I added a ref parameter to the link - `https://m.me/<PAGE_NAME>?ref=<VALUE>`.

Hope this helps!